# Why can't Java find a suitable method when the input types are interfaces and the parameter types are implementing classes?

Tags: java, class, interface

I have a class setup that looks something like this:

```
interface I{}

class A implements I{}
class B implements I{}
class C implements I{}

class D{
    I a;
    I b;

    public D(I a, I b){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public void doSomething(){
        D.someMethod(a, b);
    }

    public static someMethod(A, A){//do something}
    public static someMethod(A, B){//do something}
    public static someMethod(A, C){//do something}
    public static someMethod(B, B){//do something}
    public static someMethod(B, C){//do something}
}
```

I was really surprised to find out this doesn't compile; it'll throw an error saying it can't find a suitable method `someMethod` for types `I` and `I`. I thought it would work because if `I` were a superclass of `A`, `B` and `C` it would work. Why doesn't Java allow for this? Is there any workaround, like making `I` an abstract class?

Also, is there a name for this pattern so I don't have to keep referring to it as "this"?

Comment: How would the compiler know that there is no other class implementing `I`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At compile time, methods are chosen based on the compile-time types of the arguments provided (among other things).

Here, your arguments are of type `I`, but your `D` class does not provide any `static` methods with two parameters of type `I`.

Comment: Okay, what should I do to fix this? Would making `I` an abstract class work?

Comment: @user3002473 No, they'd still be of type `I`. You can't just _fix this_. If you'd like, describe your real use case. There are a number of solutions: visitor, observer, adapter. But they all depend on what you are trying to do.

Comment: @user3002473 No. The point is that the method is chosen at **compile time**, by looking at the type of the variable. Not at runtime, by looking at the actual type of the object.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The actual use case is this: I have classes `Polygon` , `Ellipse`, and `Rect` which implement `CollisionMask` (equivalent to `A`, `B`, `C` and `I` respectively). Now I have a `CollisionChecker` object (`D`) that takes two `CollisionMasks` and contains a bunch of methods that check for collisions between different types of collision masks (i.e. polygon to polygon or ellipse to ellipse).

Comment: @Jesper for a newcomer to Java inheritance, that isn't so helpful when you're considering the possibilities of a Set<ICommon> dispatching to different implementations of ICommon .... (but then the notion of multiple static methods differing on the subclass accepted becomes 'what are you trying to do here' territory)

Comment: @user3002473 In that case the interface `CollisionMask` is more or less useless. You need to find a different pattern to handle cases like this, [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) is a common one.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis That looks perfect for what I'm trying to do, thanks!

Comment: @biziclop Thank you biziclop! Sorry, I didn't realize it was you and not Sotiriois Delimanolis! Thank you both!

Answer (score 4):

The signature `public static someMethod(A, A)` can accept `A` or more-derived types of `A`. Similarly the `(A,B)` and so forth signatures.

You would need a method that accepts `(I,I)` in order to call it with any of the classes `A`, `B`, `C` that you sketched out above. Substitutability goes down the inheritance chain - the formal parameter you define must be the least-specific type you wish to have in common, and then any proper inheritor or implementor of that type can be passed in.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine this scenario:

```
new D( new I() {}, new I() {} ).doSomething();
```

This is perfectly legal, yet the parameters definitely won't fit any of the implementations you provided.

The compiler has no way to know or enforce that `I` will only ever be implemented by `A`, `B` or `C`.

If you find yourself in this situation, that's usually an indicator of poor design. The solution is to write the interface `I` in a way that it won't matter for the methods that work with it who implements it.

The purpose of an interface (roughly speaking) is to define common functionality. If the functionality isn't common between all implementers, there is no reason to have an interface there.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the name goes, it looks like you might be trying to use multiple dispatch.

Comment: Right, and in a single-dispatch language like Java, I think the most universally applicable pattern to apply to solve it would be the Visitor pattern.